# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\OSPanel\domains\

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

WordPress выдает ошибку
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'
Вот сам код

```
 <li class="front-page-element" id="front-page-element-placeholder">
    <label for="element-page-id">Featured post:</label>
        <select name="element-page-id">
            <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $post-<ID; ?>">
                   <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    <a href="#">Remove</a>
</li>
```

Эта ошибка относиться к строке

```
<option value="<?php echo $post-<ID; ?>">
```

Как правильно написать ?

Comment: `<option value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">`

Comment: @Denis вы бы хоть спасибо человеку сказали

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!!!  Сам не заметил эту отпечатку. Скопировал код из статьи по вордпресу. Не мог понять почему не работает у меня )))